# Monitoring Activity Lifecycle

Tags: android, android-activity, appcelerator, lifecycle, android-lifecycle

How can I monitor the Android activity lifecycle within an Appcelerator application? I'd like my application to respond to the stop, pause, resume, etc. events provided by android. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

I've read a few things regarding the creation of an "intent", but is that really necessary to supply those events? Just wondering what the simplest course of action is here.

Comment: I just entirely gave up on Appcelerator. That was my solution. Hope you find something that fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Can you place log statements like Log.debug("ClassNmae", " resumeing")  inside your app and then view the output in LogCat? Why not?

Comment: Could there be more typos?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry, didn't see the appcelerator tag.

According to the Appcelerator API docs for [Android Activities](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Activity)-

> Titanium generates lifecycle events for activities, but doesn't generate application-level start, stop, pause and resume events. To be notified when an application is paused and resumed, you must add event listeners to its individual activities.

You can find Appcelerator's guide to event handling [here](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Event+Handling).

You should be able to catch events through something such as

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('create', function(e){
    //Do something
});
```

Disclaimer: I have not worked with Appcelerator before.

Comment: Since I'm using Appcelerator, where can I override these methods? If I do override them, how can I get it to talk to the rest of my JavaScript methods?

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to look more into this. It looks like intent might still be necessary. I'll post the answer if I figure it out.